# How to upload a single image with multiple dimensions using Codeigniter?

Tags: php, image, codeigniter, image-resizing, image-upload

After uploading a single image with its original size, I can save that image both in the folder and DB.

Now I want to resize the same image into multiple dimensions while uploading. I don't know how to do this. Here is my code

Controller:

```
$newpath = './img/Pics/'.$user_id;

if (!is_dir($newpath)){
    mkdir($newpath, 0777);
}

$config['upload_path'] = $newpath;
$config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|jpeg|pdf';
$config['overwrite'] = TRUE;
$config['max_width']  = '256';
$config['max_height']  = '256';
$this->load->library('upload', $config);
$this->upload->initialize($config);
$field_name ="reg_pic";
$rgpic="0";

if (!$this->upload->do_upload($field_name)) {
    $error = $this->upload->display_errors();
    $data['error']=$error;
} 
else {
    $data = $this->upload->data();
    $regpicname= $user_id.'/'.$data['file_name'];
    $rgpic="1";
}

if ($rgpic!=0) {
    $data = array(
        'reg_image'=>$regpicname
    );
}
```

Please help me to solve this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Image resize with php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10029838/image-resize-with-php)

Comment: please give me some ideas regarding this. am totally unaware about this

Comment: Check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19218247/codeigniter-image-resize) After upload image you can use resize function and covnert into various dimension.

Answer (score 0):

use image_lib

```
  $this->load->library('image_lib');   
     $newpath = './img/Pics/'.$user_id;
               if(!is_dir($newpath)){
                mkdir($newpath, 0777);
                }
                $config['upload_path'] = $newpath;
                $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|jpeg|pdf';
                $config['overwrite'] = TRUE;
                $config['max_width']  = '256';
                $config['max_height']  = '256';
                $this->load->library('upload', $config);
                $this->upload->initialize($config);
                $field_name ="reg_pic";
                $rgpic="0";
                if ( !$this->upload->do_upload($field_name))
                {
                $error = $this->upload->display_errors();
                $data['error']=$error;
                }
                else
                {
                $data = $this->upload->data();
                $regpicname= $user_id.'/'.$data['file_name'];
                $rgpic="1";


                 if($rgpic!=0)
                 {
               $data = array(
                           'reg_image'=>$regpicname
                  );

$thumb='thumb_'.$regpicname;
                   $data=array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
                    $config['image_library'] = 'gd2';
                    $config['source_image'] =  $data['upload_data']['full_path'];
                    $config['new_image'] =  $data['upload_data']['full_path'].'/thumb/'.$thumb;
                    $config['maintain_ratio'] = FALSE;
                    $config['width'] = 160;
                    $config['height'] = 160;

                    $this->image_lib->initialize($config);

                    if(!$this->image_lib->resize())
                    {
                        echo('<pre>');
                        echo ($this->image_lib->display_errors());
                    }
                }
               }
```

for more details refer

https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/image_lib.html